# Variance of k-statistic in large-n limit

Tags: estimation, cumulants

[k-statistics](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Statistic.html) are unbiased estimators of cumulants. In the large-n limit, the formula for the $r$th k-statistic is just the formula for the $r$th cumulant in terms of central moments. But what, in the large-n limit, is the formula for the $r$th k-statistic's variance?

For any given $r$, I know how, with a lot of math and/or help from mathStatica, how to derive a formula for a k-statistic's variance, and from there I can work out the asymptotics. For example, given the formula for $V(k_3)$, it's easy to see that

$$V(k_3) = \frac{K_6 + 9 K_2 K_4 + 9 K_3^2 + 6 K_2^3}{n} + O(n^{-2})$$

But I don't see how to get this without first working out the full $V(k_3)$ formula. For a given $r$, it's clear which products of $K$s can appear, but not with which coefficients.

By the way, for h-statistics, which are unbiased estimators of the central moments, the answer is derived in Kendall's Advanced Theory. It is:

$$V(h_r) = \frac{C_{2r} - 2 r C_{r-1} C_{r+1} - r^2 C_r^2 + C_2 C_{r-1}^2}{n} + O(n^{-2})$$

I am looking for the analogous formula for k-statistics.

Comment: Isn't the variance the 2nd cumulant? So you are looking for a formula for unbiased estimators of the 2nd cumulant of arbitrary cumulants? (I don't know the answer, I just find the question interesting and make sure I understand what is being asked.)

Comment: @Chill2Macht: Yes, that's right.

Comment: 5 years later, did you found the general formula for the variance ?